# Find the inverse of $5+4\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, inverse

I'm trying to find the inverse of $5+4\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$. I know it is a unit, so there is an inverse, but I feel like I may be doing too much work in the wrong direction. Here's what I have so far:

Let $\alpha = 5+4\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4}$ and $\alpha^{-1} = a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}$ for some $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$(a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4})(5+4\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4})=1$

$=5a+6b+8c+4a\sqrt[3]{2}+5b\sqrt[3]{2}+6c\sqrt[3]{2}+3a\sqrt[3]{4}+4b\sqrt[3]{4}+5c\sqrt[3]{4}=1$

$=a(5+4\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4})+b(6+5\sqrt[3]{2}+4\sqrt[3]{4})+c(8+6\sqrt[3]{2}+5\sqrt[3]{4})=1$

and trying to solve for a,b, and c, but I don't know how?

Edit: Regrouping to $(5a+6b+8c)+(4a+5b+6c)\sqrt[3]{2}+(3a+4b+5c)\sqrt[3]{4}=1$

Comment: Work out the coefficients of powers of $2^{1/3}$.

Comment: your second to last line is the good one. Make the coefficients of the cube root of 2 and the cube root of 4 disappear

Comment: @WillJagy do you mean that instead of regrouping to make coefficients of a, b, and c, I should regroup for $(5a+6b+8c) + (4a+5b+6c)\sqrt[3]{2} + (3a+4b+5c)\sqrt{3}[4] = 1$?

Comment: YES.....................................

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks. I'm trying again but I'm still not seeing how I can make the coefficients of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\sqrt[3]{4}$ disappear. I'm trying to think of them as $x$ and $x^2$ to maybe make it look more like a polynomial in my head but I'm not getting there. Any help?

Comment: you need $5a+6b+8c = 1, \; \; $ $4a+5b+6c = 0, \; \; $ $3a+4b+5c = 0$ This can be done with an "augmented matrix"

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you that is very helpful!

Comment: Alternatively, the standard way of computing inverses in algebraic extensions is via the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963526/expressing-alpha-1-1-where-alpha3-alpha2-alpha2-0/1964370#1964370) for more details. In this case, the Euclidean algorithm shows that $1 = (-3x+2)(x^3-2) + (x^2 - 2x + 1)(3x^2 + 4x + 5)$. What do you get if you substitute $x = \sqrt[3]{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

From your last line you get three simultaneous equations for $a,b,c$ which you solve
$$5a+6b+8c=1 \\4a+5b+6c=0 \\3a+4b+5c=0\\a+b+c=0\\b+3c=1\\b+2c=0\\c=1\\b=-2\\a=1$$

Comment: the middle one should be $4a+5b+6c = 0$

Comment: @WillJagy:  thanks.  Fixed.  The solution is much simpler

Comment: Looks good.....

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
5 & 6 & 8 & 1 \\
4 & 5 & 6 & 0 \\
3 & 4 & 5 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
4 & 5 & 6 & 0 \\
3 & 4 & 5 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 4 & 5 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 4 & 5 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Apparently 
$$  a = 1, \; \; b = -2, \; \; c = 1 \; \; . $$

Answer (score 0):

Alt. hint:   let $\,x=5+4\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4}\,$, then successively multiplying with $\,\sqrt[3]{2}\,$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
5-x+4\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4} &= 0 \\
12+(5-x)\sqrt[3]{2}+4 \sqrt[3]{4} &= 0 \\
8 + 12 \sqrt[3]{2}+(5-x)\sqrt[3]{4} &= 0
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Eliminating $\,\sqrt[3]{2}\,$ and $\,\sqrt[3]{4}\,$ between the equations gives in the end:

$$
x^3 - 15 x^2 + 3 x - 1 = 0 \tag{1}
$$

Dividing the polynomial by the known factor $\,x-5-4\sqrt[3]{2}-3\sqrt[3]{4}\,$ gives the factorization:

$$
x^3 - 15 x^2 + 3 x - 1 \\
 = \big(x-5-4\sqrt[3]{2}-3\sqrt[3]{4}\big)\cdot\big(x^2 + (-10 + 4 \sqrt[3]{2} + 3 \sqrt[3]{4}) x + 1 - 2\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}\big)
$$

Finally, identifying the free terms between the two sides gives:

$$
-1 = \big(-5-4\sqrt[3]{2}-3\sqrt[3]{4}\big)\cdot\big(1 - 2\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}\big) \;\;\iff\;\; \frac{1}{5+4\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4}} = 1 - 2\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}
$$

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Another way to conclude, while avoiding the polynomial division, is to write $(1)$ as:

$$
\frac{1}{x}=x^2 - 15 x + 3 = \big(5+4\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4}\big)^2 - 15 (5+4\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4}\big) + 3 = \ldots
$$

Answer (score 0):

Mostly an observation:
$$ 5 + 4 \sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4}=(1+\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4})^2$$
so 
$$(5 + 4 \sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4})^{-1}=((1+\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4})^{-1})^2=(\sqrt[3]{2}-1)^2= 1- 2\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha=5+4\sqrt[3]{2}+3\sqrt[3]{4}$. Then
\begin{align}
\alpha\sqrt[3]{2}&=6+5\sqrt[3]{2}+4\sqrt[3]{4}\\
\alpha\sqrt[3]{4}&=8+6\sqrt[3]{2}+5\sqrt[3]{4}
\end{align}
Thus you need to find the inverse matrix of
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 6 & 8 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
3 & 4 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
With Gaussian elimination
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 6 & 8 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 6/5 & 8/5 & 1/5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/5 & -2/5 & -4/5 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2/5 & 1/5 & -3/5 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 6/5 & 8/5 & 1/5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & -4 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 & -3 & 0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 6/5 & 8/5 & 1/5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & -4 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5 & 5 & -10 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 6/5 & 8/5 & 1/5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & -4 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 6/5 & 0 & -7/5 & 16/5 & -8/5 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & -4 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
we see that the inverse is
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -4 \\
-2 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & -2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
and the inverse is
$$
1-2\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}
$$
corresponding to the first column, because this gives the effect of multiplying by the inverse of $\alpha$.

Explanation: the matrix I wrote at the beginning is the matrix of the linear map $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ induced by the multiplication by $\alpha$. Its inverse is the matrix of the linear map induced by the multiplication by $\alpha^{-1}$.